# Find the first number larger than M that results from continually multiplying 3 integers

Tags: c, math, multiplication

Problem statement: Input: 4 integers M, x, y, z where `100,000 <= M <= 1,000,000` and `-500 <= x, y, z <= 500`. We want to continually multiply the squares of these numbers until we reach a number greater than M and print that number. For example, if M = 100,000 and x = 2, y = 3, z = 4, then

```
2^2 * 3^2 * 4^2 * 2^2 * 3^2 * 4^2 = 331,776
```

Here is my attempt:

```
int M, x, y, z, xs, ys, zs, prod_square;
scanf("%d%d%d%d", &M, &x, &y, &z);
if (x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1) {
    printf("Poor input!\n");
    return 0;
}
if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0) {
    printf("Poor input!\n");
    return 0;
}

xs = x*x; ys = y*y; zs = z*z;

if (xs > M) printf("%d\n", xs);

else if (xs*ys > M) printf("%d\n", xs*ys);

else if (xs*ys*zs > M) printf("%d\n", xs*ys*zs);

else {
    prod_square = xs*ys*zs;
    double temp = (log(M))/(log(prod_square));
    int n = (int)temp;
    int result = pow(prod_square, n);

    int try1 = result * xs;
    int try2 = result * xs * ys;

    if (try1 > M) printf("%d\n", try1);
    else if (try2 > M) printf("%d\n", try2);
}
```

This works for a lot of inputs but gives the wrong answer for some edge cases. Unfortunately I don't have access to test data.

One issue could be overflow but my if statements should catch that.

Comment: *"some edge cases"* -- Which edge cases?

Comment: I don't have access to test data on the judge so all I get is "Wrong Answer!". This is a practice problem on a judge website. It works for the cases I tried but I can't think of any cases for which it doesn't work.

Comment: if any of the inputs is `0` you are just printing as bad input and continuing instead you have to return some value

Comment: Oh right, I fixed that and still get wrong answer.

Comment: Give an edge case and the exact error/result that it says

Comment: I would paranoidly distrust the behaviour of "log()" on integers. Try doing all your math on double variables. Just to get rid of one unknown while thinking.

Comment: @VidorVistrom and the one agreeing with him. OP has already stated that the edge cases are unknown and why.

Comment: The loop free solution is pretty cool. Did you try a solution with a loop, actually doing the continuos multiplying? That could detect misunderstandings of the rules.

Comment: what if your last statement `else if (try2 > M)` is also not true, then program will exit with result. So better option will be checking for the numbers in a loop until you get the right one

Comment: Using a library is allowed?

Comment: What is INT_MAX in your environment and in judges environment? I know cases where e.g. 100,000 is already out (16bit), even more so a million. I.e. how would that be caught by your ifs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a proper loop for iteration. May be following code be useful:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int M, x, y, z, prod_square;
     scanf("%d%d%d%d", &M, &x, &y, &z);
     if (x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1)
     {
         printf("Poor input!\n");
         return 0;
     }
     if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0)
     {
         printf("Poor input!\n");
         return 0;
     }

     //Now code changes
     int result=1, indx =0, vals[3];
     vals[0] = x*x;
     vals[1] = y*y;
     vals[2] = z*z;

     while(result < M)
     {
         result *= vals[indx++];
         indx %=3;
     }
     printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
 }
```

Also, for given input `M = 100,000` and `x = 2, y = 3, z = 4` then output should be

`2^2 * 3^2 * 4^2 * 2^2 * 3^2 * 4^2 = 331,776`

Comment: The logarithmic solution will work, the OP just has an error in their code. That being said, the loop solution is also a clean solution. Nice job of simplifying.

Answer (score -1):

I am shooting from the hip on this, but I am fairly certain that when you cast from `double` to `int` it truncates towards zero.  With your test case, 100,000 2,3,4 you will find that `n` will have a value of 1 after your logs, division and cast to int.  When you call `pow(prod_square, n)` you get back `prod_square`  So, in this code here you need to account for the possiblity of multiplying all three values again -

```
else {
    prod_square = xs*ys*zs;
    double temp = (log(M))/(log(prod_square));
    int n = (int)temp; // This will truncate towards 0
    int result = pow(prod_square, n);

    int try1 = result * xs;
    int try2 = result * xs * ys;

    if (try1 > M) printf("%d\n", try1);
    else if (try2 > M) printf("%d\n", try2);
    else printf("%d\n", result * prod_square);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for the downvote?  If I have missed something or need to clarify something I would be happy to do that.